# Offline SOAP Service

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, client, service-reference

I´ve got a question, is it possibile to build up a SOAP-Client with Service-Reference and an WSDL-File without the Service itself?

The case is, that I have a folder full of wsdl´s and xsd´s but the Service is hosted in a private network, so I only can call it in production but need to programm it without the service until release.

Thank you in advance.

[EDIT]

After the "Add Service Reference" way of Visual Studio didn´t work, I was using `SvcUtil.exe /language:cs "wsdl-file"` 
and it hit the following error (Note: the error is in german)

```
Fehler: wsdl:portType kann nicht importiert werden.
Detail: Beim Ausführen einer WSDL-Importerweiterung wurde eine Ausnahme ausgelöst: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Fehler: Das Schema mit dem Zielnamespace "urn:osip-aes-v2" wurde nicht gefunden.
XPath zur Fehlerquelle: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:osip-aes-v2']/wsdl:portType[@name='AntragserfassungsstellenWebservice']


Fehler: wsdl:binding kann nicht importiert werden.
Detail: Beim Importieren von wsdl:portType, der Grundlage für wsdl:binding, ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.
XPath zu wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:osip-aes-v2']/wsdl:portType[@name='AntragserfassungsstellenWebservice']
XPath zur Fehlerquelle: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:osip-aes-v2']/wsdl:binding[@name='AntragserfassungsstellenWebserviceSoapBinding']


Fehler: wsdl:port kann nicht importiert werden.
Detail: Beim Importieren von wsdl:binding, der Grundlage für wsdl:port, ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.
XPath zu wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:osip-aes-v2']/wsdl:binding[@name='AntragserfassungsstellenWebserviceSoapBinding']
XPath zur Fehlerquelle: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:osip-aes-v2']/wsdl:service[@name='AntragserfassungsstellenWebservice_v2_0']/wsdl:port[@name='FachbehoerdenWS']
```

Comment: Yes. When you add the service reference in VS, you point it at the WSDL file and it'll happily add it and generate the C# proxy for you.

Comment: Hi, I´ve tried to build a proxy with SvcUtil.exe and it says, that the porttype-tag in the wsdl file is causing some errors. I tried the svcUtil because the way "Add Service Reference" didn´t work for me.